# Como eu posso criar um loop por segundos em python, sem sleep ou delay

Tags: python, loop, tempo-real

Eu estou desenvolvendo uma programação para o EV3, com python, e o que eu queria saber é: Como eu posso criar um loop por segundos, ou seja, quero que em um determinado tempo em segundos, o robô faça as ações ininterruptamente, por isso não posso usar o sleep ou algum outro delay

```
def SeguirLinha(lado, tempo, cor):
    if lado == 'D':
        while tempo:
                if sensor() == cor:
                        MotorDireita.run( Velocidade )
                        MotorEsquerda.run( Velocidade )
                else:
                        MotorDireita.run( Velocidade )
                        MotorEsquerda.run( Velocidade * -1 )
```

O que eu quero trocar é ali em "while tempo:" e fazer com que o while rode somente durante o tempo que o usuário decidir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Experimente utilizar a biblioteca time:

```py
from time import time
tempoAEsperar=10 #Espera por 10 segundos


start = time()
while (time()-start < tempoAEsperar):
#seu código aqui
```

O retorno de time() é um número representando segundos. Como você quer saber apenas o tempo dentro daquele while, não faz diferença a referência (t=0) utilizada.

Desta forma o while roda até diferença entre os tempos ser maior do que o número de segundos especificados na variável `tempoAEsperar`, enquanto isso realizando a tarefa dentro dele repetidas vezes.

Answer (score -4):

```
import time

while True:
#seu codigo
time.sleep(10)
```